# slideshow buttons don't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, slideshow, timeline

I know this is very simple, however I have spent nearly 3 hours trying to find the answer and I can't find it.
I am working in edge animate. I believe it's JQuery that is causing the problem.

I have a slideshow of 20 hard coded images and I just want two buttons to navigate between them to make it simpler. I have one picture every 250ms and each is labeled with "f1", "f2", etc. I am using a sym.stop(); trigger on the timeline at each label and the forward button has a simple sym.play(); and the reverse button a simple sym.playReverse();. This sort of works, however it doesn't stop at the first and last frame properly. It also skips a picture each time I change direction (ex: changing from playing forwards to playing backwards)
I tried a lot of alternative codes like playing the playhead for only 250ms which I couldn't get working either

I guess an array of labels in a list could work, and moving up and down the chain with the back/fwd buttons would work, but I don't know how do that either. I would actually prefer this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Some screenshots because it's in Edge Animate and this is hopefully more comprehensible:

http://i44.tinypic.com/2qlv4o4.jpg
http://i43.tinypic.com/anih02.jpg

Comment: You will have to show us both the relevant code and HTML for us to be able to offer any meaningful advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `.stop(true, true).//next function appended if necessary`

Or perhaps, you're lacking a necessary .stop on the playReverse/First functions, or your loop is having an off-by-1 error. Hard to say without seeing ANY of your code.

Comment: There really isnt more code than i have written above. There is no loop. Thats what the backwards/forwards buttons are for.

Comment: i guess an array of labels in a list could work, and moving up and down the chain with the back/fwd buttons would work but i dont know how do that either.